# Converting comma delimited string to multiple columns in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I want to extract specific strings separated by a comma and parse across the specific columns in SQL server 2008. The table structure in SQL server is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE SAMP(COMMASEPA VARCHAR(255),X VARCHAR(10),Y VARCHAR(10),Z VARCHAR(10),A VARCHAR(10),B VARCHAR(10),C VARCHAR(10),D VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO SAMP VALUES('X=1,Y=2,Z=3',null,null,null,null,null,null,null),
('X=3,Y=4,Z=5,A=6',null,null,null,null,null,null,null),
('X=1,Y=2,Z=3,A=5,B=6,C=7,D=8',null,null,null,null,null,null,null)
```

I want the string to be separated based on comma and ONE of the strings in `[x/y/z/a/b/c/d]`. For example in the result table for first row X=1 should be in X col, Y=2 should be in Y col, Z=3 should be in Z col. Please input any ideas in doing this. Thank you…

Comment: I had the same problem at one time. You can go to here http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html or http://www.apexa.net/Blog/web_design_Blog_20080619.aspx. Both of these pages show you methods to unpack/parse a list/array into a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see this working on SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8c3ee/32

Here's the meat of it:

```
with parsed as (
  select
  commasepa,
  root.value('(/root/s/col[@name="X"])[1]', 'varchar(20)') as X,
  root.value('(/root/s/col[@name="Y"])[1]', 'varchar(20)') as Y,
  root.value('(/root/s/col[@name="Z"])[1]', 'varchar(20)') as Z,
  root.value('(/root/s/col[@name="A"])[1]', 'varchar(20)') as A,
  root.value('(/root/s/col[@name="B"])[1]', 'varchar(20)') as B,
  root.value('(/root/s/col[@name="C"])[1]', 'varchar(20)') as C,
  root.value('(/root/s/col[@name="D"])[1]', 'varchar(20)') as D
FROM
(
select
   commasepa,
   CONVERT(xml,'<root><s><col name="' + REPLACE(REPLACE(COMMASEPA, '=', '">'),',','</col></s><s><col name="') + '</col></s></root>') as root
FROM
  samp
) xml
)
update 
  samp
  set
  samp.x = parsed.x,
  samp.y = parsed.y,
  samp.z = parsed.z,
  samp.a = parsed.a,
  samp.b = parsed.b,
  samp.c = parsed.c,
  samp.d = parsed.d
from
  parsed
where
  parsed.commasepa = samp.commasepa;
```

Full disclosure - I'm the author of sqlfiddle.com

This works by first converting each commasepa string into an XML object that looks like this:

```
<root>
 <s>
  <col name="X">1</col>
 </s>
 <s>
  <col name="Y">2</col>
 </s>
  ....
</root>
```

Once I have the string in that format, I then use the xquery options that SQL Server 2005 (and up) support, which is the `.value('(/root/s/col[@name="X"])[1]', 'varchar(20)')` part.  I select each of the potential columns individually, so they are normalized and populated when available.  With that normalized format, I define the result set with a Common Table Expression (CTE) that I called 'parsed'.  This CTE is then joined back in the update statement, so that the values can be populated in the original table.

Comment: thanks a lot for the input, its working..if possible can you please explain the root.value in the code and the steps you followed..Thank you..I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of a Split function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitStrings]
(
   @List       VARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
   RETURN ( SELECT Item FROM ( SELECT Item = x.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)') 
      FROM  ( SELECT [XML] = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
              + '</i>').query('.') ) AS a CROSS APPLY [XML].nodes('i') AS x(i)
          ) AS y WHERE Item IS NOT NULL
   );
GO
```

You can do it this way:

```
;WITH x AS
(
    SELECT s.*, f.Item
        FROM #samp AS s
        CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings(s.COMMASEPA, ',') AS f
), p AS 
( 
    SELECT x.COMMASEPA, 
        X = MAX(CASE WHEN x.Item LIKE 'X=%' THEN x.Item END),
        Y = MAX(CASE WHEN x.Item LIKE 'Y=%' THEN x.Item END),
        Z = MAX(CASE WHEN x.Item LIKE 'Z=%' THEN x.Item END),
        A = MAX(CASE WHEN x.Item LIKE 'A=%' THEN x.Item END),
        B = MAX(CASE WHEN x.Item LIKE 'B=%' THEN x.Item END),
        C = MAX(CASE WHEN x.Item LIKE 'C=%' THEN x.Item END),
        D = MAX(CASE WHEN x.Item LIKE 'D=%' THEN x.Item END)
    FROM x GROUP BY x.COMMASEPA
)
UPDATE s SET X = p.X, Y = p.Y, Z = p.Z, 
  A = p.A, B = p.B, C = p.C, D = p.D
FROM #samp AS s INNER JOIN p 
ON p.COMMASEPA = s.COMMASEPA;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @SAMP TABLE
(
  COMMASEPA VARCHAR(255),
  X VARCHAR(10),
  Y VARCHAR(10),
  Z VARCHAR(10),
  A VARCHAR(10),
  B VARCHAR(10),
  C VARCHAR(10),
  D VARCHAR(10)
)
INSERT INTO @SAMP VALUES
('X=1,Y=2,Z=3',null,null,null,null,null,null,null),
('X=3,Y=4,Z=5,A=6',null,null,null,null,null,null,null),
('X=1,Y=2,Z=3,A=5,B=6,C=7,D=8',null,null,null,null,null,null,null)

update S set
  X = case when P.X > 3 then substring(T.COMMASEPA, P.X, charindex(',', T.COMMASEPA, P.X) - P.X) end,
  Y = case when P.Y > 3 then substring(T.COMMASEPA, P.Y, charindex(',', T.COMMASEPA, P.Y) - P.Y) end,
  Z = case when P.C > 3 then substring(T.COMMASEPA, P.Z, charindex(',', T.COMMASEPA, P.Z) - P.Z) end,
  A = case when P.A > 3 then substring(T.COMMASEPA, P.A, charindex(',', T.COMMASEPA, P.A) - P.A) end,
  B = case when P.B > 3 then substring(T.COMMASEPA, P.B, charindex(',', T.COMMASEPA, P.B) - P.B) end,
  C = case when P.C > 3 then substring(T.COMMASEPA, P.C, charindex(',', T.COMMASEPA, P.C) - P.C) end,
  D = case when P.D > 3 then substring(T.COMMASEPA, P.D, charindex(',', T.COMMASEPA, P.D) - P.D) end
from @SAMP as S
  cross apply (select ','+S.COMMASEPA+',') as T(COMMASEPA)
  cross apply (select charindex(',X=', T.COMMASEPA)+3 as X,
                      charindex(',Y=', T.COMMASEPA)+3 as Y,
                      charindex(',Z=', T.COMMASEPA)+3 as Z,
                      charindex(',A=', T.COMMASEPA)+3 as A,
                      charindex(',B=', T.COMMASEPA)+3 as B,
                      charindex(',C=', T.COMMASEPA)+3 as C,
                      charindex(',D=', T.COMMASEPA)+3 as D) as P
```

Comment: Thanks..it solves the problem for the table I quoted as an example as all the numbers are greater than 3, but I think Jakes answer is more universal...thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Correct my line of thinking here...

Instead of trying to "Comma" delimit a field it would be more prudent to have a second table where you can put your name/value pairs in.

```
Modify SAMP to have the following field:
ID - integer - Primary Key Auto increment

Create a table NVP
ID - integer - Primary Key Auto increment
SAMPID - integer Foreign key SAMP.ID
Name - varchar(255) - or any realistic size
Value - varchar(255) - or any realistic size

This will allow for the following:
1.  Unlimited fields
2.  Faster Data Access
3.  Since you are not trying to shove several values into 1 field, you now don't have to worry about running out of space.
4.  Less code to worry about trying to split/join data
5.  No longer restricted where you can't store a "," as one of your names or values.
```

SQL tables should always be relational to take advantage of the power SQL has to offer.