# Extract words from comma-separated string to individual rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split, sql-server-2014

I have the following table:

```
(RowNumber int, Names (varchar(50))
```

[image]

I need an update statement or function that separates all words between commas into different columns as:

[image]

I have tried the following script but it does not work as in the column `[Names]` there are different numbers of commas in each row and cannot add `NULL` values.

```
select * 
from [TTT2] mt
cross apply ( select str = mt.[Names] + ',,' ) f1
cross apply ( select p1 = charindex( ',', str )) ap1
cross apply ( select p2 = charindex( ',', str, p1 + 1)) ap2
cross apply ( select p3 = charindex( ',', str, p2 + 1)) ap3
cross apply ( select p4 = charindex( ',', str, p3 + 1)) ap4
cross apply ( select p5 = charindex( ',', str, p4 + 1)) ap5
cross apply ( select p6 = charindex( ',', str, p5 + 1)) ap6
cross apply ( select p7 = charindex( ',', str, p6 + 1)) ap7
cross apply ( select p8 = charindex( ',', str, p7 + 1)) ap8
cross apply ( select p9 = charindex( ',', str, p8 + 1)) ap9
cross apply ( select p10 = charindex( ',', str, p9 + 1)) ap10
cross apply ( select col1 = substring( str, 1, p1-1 )                   
, col2 = substring( str, p1+1, p2-p1-1 )
, Col3 = substring( str, p2+1, p3-p2-1 )
, Col4 = substring( str, p3+1, p4-p3-1 )
, Col5 = substring( str, p4+1, p5-p4-1 )
, Col6 = substring( str, p5+1, p6-p5-1 )
, Col7 = substring( str, p6+1, p7-p6-1 )
, Col8 = substring( str, p7+1, p8-p7-1 )
, Col9 = substring( str, p8+1, p9-p8-1 )
, Col10 = substring( str, p9+1, p10-p9-1 )
          ) ParsedData
```

Please help me with vegetables :-)

Thank you

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589282/converting-comma-delimited-string-to-multiple-columns-in-sql-server

Comment: Please post an exhaustive set of input data **in text format** (not inside an image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could work, with some limitations. And I am not sure if you need columns to always containt same values (Base on your sample data, this is what it seems to be). I have included a row with VegX, A and Z to illustrate this
Hope that helps

```
--  Get the sample input table
declare     @intable    table
    (RowNumber int, Names varchar(50))
insert into @intable 
values 
(1, 'Veg A, Veg B, Veg C, Veg D'), 
(2, 'Veg A'), 
(3, 'Veg A, Veg B, Veg C'), 
(4, 'Veg X, Veg Y, Veg Z')

-- Limitation : Will work only if list is not greater than 12 vegetables.. If more needed, need to build a query and then execute

-- Step1 : Split the content using string_split 
;with sco as (
select  rownumber, ltrim(Rtrim(Value)) as myvalue
from    @intable
        cross apply string_split(names, ',') t2),
-- Step 2 build col name using dense_rank
sco2 as (
    select  rownumber, myvalue, 'col' + format(dense_rank() over(partition by rownumber order by myvalue), '0') as mycol
    from sco)
-- Final select using PIVOT to put rows in columns
select  * from sco2
PIVOT
(
    min(myvalue)
    FOR mycol in (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12)) as ptv
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Static version

This solution will handle **exactly 8 columns**:

```
declare @tmp table (RowNumber int, [Names] varchar(max))
insert into @tmp values
(1,'alfaalfa sprouts, bean sprouts , black beans, black-eyed peas, borlotti bean, broad beans, chickpeas, garbanzos'),
(2,'alfaalfa sprouts, bean sprouts'),
(3,'alfaalfa sprouts, bean sprouts , black beans, black-eyed peas')

;WITH Splitted AS 
( 
    SELECT   CAST('<x>' + REPLACE([Names],',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS Names 
    FROM @tmp 
) 
SELECT Names.value(N'/x[1]','varchar(max)') AS Col1 
      ,Names.value(N'/x[2]','varchar(max)') AS Col2 
      ,Names.value(N'/x[3]','varchar(max)') AS Col3 
      ,Names.value(N'/x[4]','varchar(max)') AS Col4 
      ,Names.value(N'/x[5]','varchar(max)') AS Col5 
      ,Names.value(N'/x[6]','varchar(max)') AS Col6 
      ,Names.value(N'/x[7]','varchar(max)') AS Col7 
      ,Names.value(N'/x[8]','varchar(max)') AS Col8 
FROM Splitted;
```

Results:

[image]

### 2. Dynamic version

This solution handles **any number of columns**. In this example I added a new vegetable, so that a new column (col9) appears in the results:

```
declare @col_num int
declare @counter int=1
create table #tmp (RowNumber int, [Names] varchar(max))
insert into #tmp values
(1,'alfaalfa sprouts, bean sprouts , black beans, black-eyed peas, borlotti bean, broad beans, chickpeas, garbanzos, myNewVegetable!'),
(2,'alfaalfa sprouts, bean sprouts'),
(3,'alfaalfa sprouts, bean sprouts , black beans, black-eyed peas')

select @col_num = max(len([Names]) - len(replace([Names],',','')) + 1)  from #tmp

declare @sql nvarchar(max)=''
set @sql  = @sql +';WITH Splitted AS ('
set @sql  = @sql +'SELECT   CAST(''<x>'' + REPLACE([Names],'','',''</x><x>'') + ''</x>'' AS XML) AS Names '
set @sql  = @sql +'FROM #tmp) '
set @sql  = @sql +'SELECT '

while @counter <= @col_num
    begin
        if @counter > 1
            set @sql  = @sql + ','
        set @sql  = @sql +'Names.value(N''/x['+ cast(@counter as varchar(max)) +']'',''varchar(max)'') AS Col' + cast(@counter as varchar(max)) + ' '
        set @counter = @counter + 1
    end
set @sql  = @sql +'FROM Splitted; '
exec(@sql)
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Dear Andrea, Thank you for your input. I tried the dynamic version but as the table is 500,000 rows I get the following error: Msg 9455, Level 16, State 1, Line 176
XML parsing: line 1, character 98, illegal qualified name character

Comment: @l217 First of all you should post a relevant sample of your input data. To find the data that cause the problem you can get the dinamically generated query with: `print @sql` and then manually execute it